# Postgres COPY command in prepared statements

Tags: postgresql, go

Apologies if this is duplicated elsewhere, I have been reading through the Postgres documentation [on extended queries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol-flow.html#PROTOCOL-FLOW-EXT-QUERY) and i am unsure how the following situation can occur. From the documentation:

> The possible responses to Execute are the same as those described above for queries issued via simple query protocol, except that Execute doesn't cause ReadyForQuery or RowDescription to be issued.

Reviewing the simple query section, its responses include `CopyInResponse` and `CopyOutResponse`. However when testing, i cant seem to write a valid prepared statement that includes a `COPY TO` or `COPY FROM` operation. Is there another mechanism Extended queries can use that result in one of the above commands being triggered (or is there a valid way to write a prepared COPY statement that don't include the aforementioned verbs)?

NOTE: I am aware that the question of how to handle parameters in COPY statements has been answered before. I want to validate if there is an error in the Postgres documentation, or if there is some operation other than the two attempted below that could result in an extended query returning a `CopyIn` or `CopyOut` response.

In Go, if i try execute a simple prepared statement:

```
_, err = db.Exec("COPY (SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE ext_id = $1 ) TO '/tmp/file.csv' WITH CSV HEADER;", "customer1")
```

it returns

```
pq: got 1 parameters but the statement requires 0
```

If i try explicitly PREPARE:

```
PREPARE example(text) AS
    COPY (SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE ext_id = $1 ) TO '/tmp/file.csv' WITH CSV HEADER;
```

I get:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "COPY"
LINE 2:  COPY (SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE ext_id = $1 ) TO '/tmp/file....
```

Comment: As to `PREPARE` example see [PREPARE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html): *statement Any SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, MERGE, or VALUES statement.*. So `COPY` is not allowed.